# order of items in the for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this data

```
  1.  def lem(str):
    return synsets for every str

  2. list_terms = list of terms
  3. list_st = list of strings as input for the function
```

What needed here is to find in the list of terms any string as output of the function. The problem with me is the order of the items in the code below

```
if any(i in list_terms for i in lem(item) for item in list_st):
    do somethind
```

This code gives the error

```
NameError: name 'item' is not defined
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Did you try to switch the for-loops? Like `...for item in list_st for i in lem(item)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, do you really *need* it to be a list comprehension here?
I think the problem is more clearly visible if you write this down more explicitly:

```
terms = []
for item in list_st:
    for i in lem(item):
        if i in list_terms:
            terms.append(i)
if terms:
     do_something
```

This is a bit ugly in that it follows the [Arrow Anti Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern), but makes a bit more clear what is going on here.

If you convert this to a list comprehension, remember that you need to **reverse** the order or the loop declarations (see the comment above).